# Static-Shielding bags

Tags: antistatic

How many times can I use the Static-Shielding bags? I usually use this kind of bags to prevent to damage electronics. So when I need to touch some circuits, firstly I touch the bag. The problem here is I have already used the bag. Is it safe to do this or not?

Comment: That's not how static shielding bags work. Touching a static shielding bag before working on electronics has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: An anti-static bag isn't a magic bag to put static electricity into.  It's something you put components into to protect them from static electricity during storage or transport.

Answer (score 5):

You can use anti-static bags indefinite amount of times, until they are damaged.

> So when I need to touch some circuits, firstly I touch the bag. ... Is it safe to do this or not?

This is not what anti-static bags are made for. To discharge yourself you should use wrist strap or discharge mat connected to ground. Alternatively use ESD-shoes.

Comment: I don't understand. So what is the aim of this kind of bags if they are not used to prevent to break electronics?

Comment: Bag is indeed used to store and protect components inside. It has conductive coating which prevents static charge from getting to the components. However you misuse the bag by trying to discharge yourself.

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi Think of static electricity as a bunch of little ants. The bag keeps the ants out. But if you have ants on you or on the bag, touching the bag won't get rid of the ants.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of bags:
Polypopolene - usually pink or blue. These have a very thin layer of ESD shielding material on their surface and do not work well for ESD shielding. They are used for shipping, and don't work well after that. Companies that implement strict ESD controls avoid them entirely.

Mylar - silver colored aluminized bags. They have an aluminum coating over the plastic which is more durable and provides better protection. These can be reused. Athough if the aluminum coating gets damaged I would throw them out.